# Strange characters in email that cannot be ingested by imap server

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, imap

I am writing a tool that is able to backup and restore emails in Gmail via IMAP in python.
In some case the emails that are backed up from Gmail contain weird characters: ^@ that then cannot be reingested by Gmail IMAP.

```
Delivered-To: xxxxx@lxxxxxx
Received: by 1x.xx.xx.xx with SMTP id jjjjjjjj;
        Tue, 14 Jun 2011 16:56:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by x.x.x.x with SMTP id xxxx.xxx;
        Tue, 14 Jun 2011 16:56:16 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <foo.bar@email.com>
Delivery-Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2010 17:58:56 +0200
Received: from xxxxx (xxxxx [x.x.x.x])
    by xxxx (node=xxx) with ESMTP (xxx)
    id xxx ; Mon, 23 Aug 2010 17:58:56 +0200
Received: from [x] (x)
    by x (x) with x (x)
    id x; Mon, 23 Aug 2010 17:58:50 +0200
Message-ID: <x@foo.com>
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2010 17:58:48 +0200
From: Foo Bar <foo.bar@email.com>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100802             Thunderbird/3.1.2
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: bar.foo@email.com <x>
Subject: The subject
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Provags-ID: xxxxxxxxxxx=
Envelope-To: foo.bar@email.com


  Hello All,

blah blah blah


^@
```

At the end their is this special character. Sometimes it appears in other emails in the middle.
When I store the email on disk (eml format) I just save it and revive it.

The encoding seems correct.

What is this character ? 
Am I doing something wrong when I store the email in eml.

A bit of guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `^@` is a Null Character.  Not sure how it's getting there.  Could you paste your code?  Reference: http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Comment: The email is 8bit, `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`. Not all systems / software cope with 8bit mail. As @ZnArK says, `^@` is a common representation of NULL.

Comment: I think it is inserted when the email is originally created. Then Gmail Imap doesn't want to accept it. I have one question though. There is the IMAP communication and SSL over it. Do you think that the SSL layer could add it ? The code is pretty straight forward, I get the email via python imaplib and save it in a file. The file is open with 'wb'. Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can strip null characters from the body of the email prior to sending them back to Google.**

Longer answer:

Old email (according to [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)) was allowed to have null characters. New email (according to [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), circa 2003) is not allowed to have null characters. Note RFC 2822 reads: "Differences from earlier standards... ASCII 0 (null) removed."

It's entirely possible that Gmail accepts 822-style emails via SMTP (that's how the email first got to your inbox) but only 2822-style emails via IMAP (which is why you can't put it back via IMAP).

** Note: Don't blindly strip nulls from MIME documents included in the email. RFC 2822 "specifies that messages are made up of characters in the US-ASCII range of 1 through 127.  There are other documents, specifically the MIME document series [RFC2045, RFC2046, RFC2047, RFC2048, RFC2049], that extend [RFC 2822] to allow for values outside of that range."